# Freeze JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I have a class with certain properties and have created new objects based on them. I don't want one object to have certain property added to the class after I have created the object. I have tried object freezing the object. But it does not work. Was wondering if there was a way to do so?

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
Object.freeze(myMother); // does not work

Person.prototype.favColor = 'green'; // this is reflected in myMother object as well which i don't want
```

Comment: Don't use a class, use an object. Using a class for such a data structure provides no benefits and makes your code unnecessarily complicated. So simple to write `function person(first, last, age, eye) { return {first, last, age, eye}; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to (not) change the prototype object, so you have to Freeze the prototype object instead:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
Object.freeze(Person.prototype); // now it does work

Person.prototype.favColor = 'green';
console.log(myMother);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... Out of curiosity is there a way for only the myFather object to inherit the new properties and not the myMother object?

Comment: You could create new classes that extend Person, and have one subclass's prototype frozen and the other left alone, but `Object.freeze(MotherClass.prototype)` would clearly only apply to MotherClass - it wouldn't apply to Person. Better to avoid inheritance chains though.

Comment: @ShrujanShetty This appears to be kind of an XY problem. Why would you do that? If you have many father objects that have other properties than just a person or a mother, then create a subclass of person. That’s the whole point of OO. I also strongly disagree with CertainPerfomance that you should avoid inheritance chains.